# Multiple files doesn't load via form

Tags: php, image-uploading

I have HTML form:

```
<form id="add_user_info" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <div class="multi_photos multi1">
        <input type="file" name="user_passport_photo[]" placeholder="Add Photo">
        <input type="file" name="user_passport_photo[]" placeholder="Add Photo">
    </div>

    <div class="multi_photos multi2">
        <input type="file" name="user_voditel_prava[]" placeholder="Add photo">
        <input type="file" name="user_voditel_prava[]" placeholder="Add photo">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="add_driver_by_editor" class="btn add_user_info">Add</button>
</form>
```

and PHP code:

```
$data = $_POST;
if(isset($data['add_driver_by_editor'])) {

    $driver_id = $data['user_phone'];
    $one_driver_path = 'images/' . $driver_id . '/';

    mkdir($one_driver_path . 'passport', 0777, true);
    for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['user_passport_photo']['name']); $i++) {
        $path_tmp = $one_driver_path . '/passport' . '/' . basename($_FILES['user_passport_photo']['name'][$i]);
        if( move_uploaded_file($_FILES['user_passport_photo']['tmp_name'][$i], $path_tmp) ) {
            $driver->driver_passport = 'images/' . $driver_id . '/' . 'passport/';
        } else {
            echo "Error";
        }
    }

    for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['user_voditel_prava']['name']); $i++) {
        (LINE 57) $path_tmp = $one_driver_path . '/voditel_prava' . '/' . basename($_FILES['user_voditel_prava']['name'][$i]); 
        (LINE 58) if( move_uploaded_file($_FILES['user_voditel_prava']['tmp_name'][$i], $path_tmp) ) { 
            $driver->driver_prava= 'images/' . $driver_id . '/' . 'passport/';
        } else {
            echo "Error";
        }
    }

}
```

When I upload several files into each "user_passport_photo[]" and "user_voditel_right[]", the first script works fine, but the second one (identical) doesn't work. Gives an error message:

[image]

on line 57 and 58

Comment: So, `print_r($_FILES['user_voditel_prava'])`. What do you see?

Comment: Array ( [name] => [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 4 [size] => 0 )

Comment: so there is an error `[error] => 4` while you upload files

Comment: Error is 4 so it means no file was uploaded

Comment: But I upload them into the fields =((

Comment: Can you show your entire form?

Comment: https://imgur.com/20zJL1a